# How to do corners right with Cocoa Touch (iOS) Graphics Context Drawing?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I am just experimenting, getting used to drawing with Quartz 2D on iOS.  I drew three offset squares (perimeter lines only) using Graphics Context move(to:) and addLine(_:CGPoint) functions.  Consider the following image of the result:
[image]

I am only showing the top part but it is enough to document my question.  You can see that the upper left corner of each square is incomplete (sharp square corners) where as the upper right looks OK.  The two bottom corners are like the upper right in being exactly what I expected.

So, my starting position for adding these lines (width set to 3.0) is the upper left corner which is located using Graphics Context move(to: CGPoiint).  Each subsequent corner is arrived by merely calling the addLine(_:CGPoint) method.

So, what am I doing wrong that results in the "broken" corner as shown.  How do I get that upper left corner to look like all others?

Code generating diagram

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let colors: [(CGFloat,CGFloat,CGFloat)] = 
          [(1.0,0.0,0.0),(0.25,1.0,0.5),(0.5,0.5,1.0)]
    let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    c.setLineWidth(3.0)
    var dx = 0
    var dy = 0
    for q in 1...3 {
        c.move(to:CGPoint(x:dx+50, y:dy+50))
        c.addLine(to:CGPoint(x: dx+200, y: dy+50))
        c.addLine(to:CGPoint(x: dx+200, y: dy+200))
        c.addLine(to:CGPoint(x: dx+50,y: dy+200))
        c.addLine(to:CGPoint(x: dx+50,y: dy+50))
        c.setStrokeColor(
             red:colors[q-1].0
            ,green:colors[q-1].1
            ,blue:colors[q-1].2,alpha:1.0)
        c.strokePath()
        dx += 20
        dy += 20
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The artifact is caused by the thicker line width. All of the dimensions you give are for the center of each line. Since you give a line width of 3, each line is filled 1.5 points each side of the center line.

You could account for this in the first and last coordinate but that's error prone and depends on the line width.

The better solution is to use `closePath()` instead of adding the last line.

```
c.move(to:CGPoint(x:dx+50, y:dy+50))
c.addLine(to:CGPoint(x: dx+200, y: dy+50))
c.addLine(to:CGPoint(x: dx+200, y: dy+200))
c.addLine(to:CGPoint(x: dx+50,y: dy+200))
//c.addLine(to:CGPoint(x: dx+50,y: dy+50)) // not needed any more
c.closePath()
```

`closePath()` will draw a straight line from the last point to the first point of the path. This also deals with properly filling in that little artifact at the join at the location of the first point.

The simplest solution is to use `UIBezierPath` to draw the rectangle but doing it all manually is a good way to learn.

Comment: thanks -- just the sort of answer that I was hoping to get:  Simple, Obvious (once you know it), and Not a Kludge.  I was actually planning to play around with Bezier Paths next.